# ComboBox to filter data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to make a ComboBox dropdown with some criteria inside.
[image]

I want to Filter by Total Product Holding.

This ComboBox is in "Main Menu" sheet, and the data to be filtered is in "Consolidated Database" sheet.
[image]

So, when I select the criteria from the dropdown list, the data in the "Consolidated Database" is filtered based on that selection.

For example, I select "1" from the dropdown list, then the data in the "Consolidated Database" is filtered by "1" on Column BC ("SUM PH ALL"), and all the data in that worksheet also filtered by that criteria.
What should happen if I select "1" in the dropdown list in the "Main Menu" sheet:
[image]

The VBA code says error.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lastr As Integer
    lastr = Range("BC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Consolidated Database").Range("BC2:BC" & lastr).AutoFilter _
    Field:=55, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=x1FilterValues
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "SUM_PH_ALL"
End Sub
```

Comment: *It keeps saying error...* What error are you getting?

Comment: `x1FilterValues`  should be `xlFilterValues`

Comment: @SamuelEverson the error message was "Application-defined or object-defined error". But nevermind, turns out there was a typo in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah yess, thank you so much for pointing that out, I thought I was using a wrong code, but it was a typo after all :D

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine, turns out there was a typo before.
Thanks to @TimWilliams for pointing out my typo.
So, here is the code after I corrected it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim lastr As Integer

lastr = Range("BC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Consolidated Database").Range("BC2:BC" & lastr).AutoFilter Field:=55, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub

 

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

Me.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "SUM_PH_ALL"

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI if you get into the habit of always using `Option Explicit` then it will save you from problems like this...